# Trying to connect Flask backend to React frontend using SSL

Tags: python, reactjs, ssl, flask, amazon-ec2

My backend is an AWS EC2 server that runs on flask, I'm trying to port over my code from http to https. I've used letsencrypt and certbot to create valid certificates. My flask backend accesses the certs and then calls the host. I tried adding SSLify after looking through other posts ( and seeing that it can be used with Flask, but it didn't change anything.

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sslify import SSLify
from OpenSSL import SSL

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
sslify = SSLify(app)
sslify

if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = ("../../../../etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.name/fullchain.pem","../../../../etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.name/p$
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

On the React frontend side, I'm using axios

```
axios.post('https://127.0.0.1:5000/run_query', postData, axiosConfig)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log("Successful connection");
    console.log(response.data);
    influencerList = response.data.query_results;
    console.log(influencerList);
    currentComponent.setState({IL: influencerList});
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

using `app.run` options I listed above on the backend returns 
`xhr.js:178 OPTIONS https://127.0.0.1:5000/run_query net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the Google Chrome Browser Console.

I'm runnning nginx on Linux AMI. The certificates are for RehlOS/CentOS generated through letsencrypt and certbot. My Nginx error.log doesn't return anything, running the backend python file doesn't log anything anymore, like it did before going from HTTP. It just displays this:

```
* Running on https://ec2-34-209-86-220.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
```

I also tried changing the `post` URL to `https://ec2-34-209-86-220.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/run-query` instead of `https://127.0.0.1:5000/run_query` but got the exact same error.

I hope it's something simple, any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: did you open port 5000 in your EC2 instance's security groups? Also, I've found that references to localhost on EC2 should indeed be replaced by the instance's public IP, as you mention at the bottom of your post. Make sure you use the public address of the host everywhere you use axios. I believe you'll also want to change app.run host to '0.0.0.0' to listen on all interfaces.